# Options to create a .ics url from google sheet

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, google-apps-script

I have a set of events that our department is coordinating (lectures, gatherings, etc)  I want to provide a .ics url that people can add to their Google (or outlook or whatever) Calendars via [+ Other Calendars] >> [From URL].   I have looked for API integrations like Zapier, but that wants direct access to calendars and I want it to be one way.  I can automate getting the data into a Google Spreadsheet but cannot figure out where to go from there.

I have found some App Scripts that seem to get close to there. ex: [How to automatically add a schedule from Google Sheet into Calendar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOggwSls7xQ) however I want the calendar to also Update the events if they change in the original data source.

Comment: "however I want the calendar to also Update the events if they change in the original data source." That's a tall order since you don't want to create/end up with duplicated events . Sounds like (assuming it is actually possible) you would have to create two transactions - one to delete the original/event, and a second to add the new/modified event. Only problem is that a user who hadn't processed an initial event, wouldn't have an 'existing" event to delete. This is all because "I want it to be one way"; but what if you created a Google calendar specifically for this purpose. Would that help?

Comment: Yes, it isn't clear why your aren't managing the events in the calendar yiu are sharing out.

Comment: Because the business needs calls for managing the event details in the crm.